# Why ngFor async pipe needs Observable<any[]> instead of Observable<any>?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactivex

I have the following template:

```
*ngFor="let contact of contacts | async"
```

Where:

```
contacts: Observable<any>;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
    of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Why does ngFor async pipe need `Observable<any[]>` instead of `Observable<T>`?

Comment: how are you fetching `contacts`?

Answer (score 3):

This is not because of the `async` pipe.

The `contacts` Observable emits objects instead of an array and you can't iterate objects with `*ngFor`. That's what the error message says.

So the problem is with `contacts`. Have a look at what it really emits.

Comment: I used async to catch emitted objects from Observable. What's the point of getting the whole contact list at once and not item by item otherwise?

Comment: async in combination with the ngFor is not meant to emit item per item. If you want to use so, you can use the scan() operator

Comment: @clemtoy kvetis is right. The `async` pipe just shows what you emit. It's not made to "collect" items as you emit them them. That's what `scan` operator is good for.

Answer (score 2):

ngFor needs to see an iterable of `contacts' (as already stated by @martin), which also means it needs to know the **extent** of what it's iterating, i.e how many items are you intending to display.

The simplest way forward is to add another property which uses the `toArray()` operator to the component, and use that in the template.

**template**

```html
<div *ngFor="let contact of contactsList | async">
  From contactsList: {{contact}}
</div>
```

**component**

```js
contactsList = this.contacts.toArray();
```

However, if you want to display something before contacts observable **completes** (i.e add to ngFor with each contact emitted), you need a buffering observable.

```js
private buffer = []; 
contactsList = Observable.of(this.buffer); 

ngOnInit() {
  this.contacts.subscribe(contact => {
    this.buffer.push(contact)
  })
}
```

**Demo**: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtqpe4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)